# Strange behaviour of the bootstrap button on focus into pagination

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap v2.2.2

And this is my button:

```
<div class="pagination ">
     <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-large"> 
             <i class="icon-fast-forward"></i>
         </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

However, when I try to focus on button I get strange behavior of colors:

Demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/853/)

The fix is to remove `pagination` class or `<ul>` tag

How can I fix it?

Thank you,

(***comment*: I'm not interesting to use bootstrap 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the tag from anchor to button, it solves your display issue.  I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/854/)

```
 <button class="btn btn-success">  <i class="icon-fast-forward"></i> </button>
```